# C# WPF How to add dynamic row item to DataGrid without binding it to any type?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Im writing program that creates dynamic DataGrid based on user input, user only provides column names,row names, based on that I need to generate empty DataGrid that allows user to enter value.But since I can't find anything for my case, My columns will contain numbers and I can't create type to hold them. The solutions I found only work if you create type and then use properties of that type, but I can't predict how much properties would I need so I would kinda need to add array as row.

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
private void generate_DataGrid(string[] headers)
{
    foreach (string h in headers) {
        DataGridTextColumn gridColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
        gridColumn.Header = h;
        tabelaDataGrid.Columns.Add(gridColumn);
    }

    int[] row1 = new int[3];
    int[] row2 = new int[3];
    tabelaDataGrid.Items.Add(row1);
    tabelaDataGrid.Items.Add(row2);
}
```

The solution above will generate empty row, but I can't edit them:

> "System.InvalidOperationException: ''EditItem' is not allowed for this view.'"

Or maybe should I search for some other solution like spreadsheet library?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to bind the `DataGrid` to a DataTable and then just adding Rows and Columns like this: (Please note `BindableBase` is part of the `Prism` framework; if you don't use it search for INotifyPropertyChanged Interface to see how to implement it from scratch)

```
 public class DataGridExampleViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private DataTable _dataTable;
    public DataTable DataTable
    {
        get { return _dataTable; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _dataTable, value); }
    }

    public DataGridExampleViewModel()
    {

        //Create a empty dataTable
        DataTable = new DataTable();
    }

    //Add a column to the DataTable the Type is optional
    public void AddColumn(string columnName, Type dataType)
    {
        DataTable.Columns.Add(columnName, dataType);
    }

    //Add an empty row to the DataTable
    public void AddRow()
    {
        //Create a new row
        var row = DataTable.NewRow();

        //Add the row to the DataTable
        DataTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }      
}
```

If you are new to WPF and not familiar with data binding i strongly recommend you to look for it.

Side note:
Check out Prism & MahApps.Metro both are great libraries for building WPF apps.

Comment: The question explicitly stated, that binding is not desired.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry for missing that! It's new to me using WPF without bindings. Is there an explicite reason for NOT using bindings?

Comment: On reading the question  mindfully: What i think the questioner don't want is creating a class and binding the DataGrid.Columns against the properties of this class. Cause what he want is more generic. So i think he is not against binding in general. Please correct me if i'm wrong.